# Knowing which Classes to utilise in Magento 2 for Dependency Injection

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I've begun learning Magento 2 recently, whereas I've gotten a pretty good grasp of understanding the methodology of DI.

1. Add the expected Interfaces & Classes in `di.xml`
2. Add to Constructor of your Controller
3. Pass the initiated class to a protected member & begin developing.

However I've gotten to that point where I'm asking myself, "I need to check existence of a Category" at Controller level. I begin hitting `CTRL` + `Space` for Auto-complete on my IDE, digging through hundreds of possible similarly named Classes:

- `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\`
- `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryManagement`
- `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository`
- `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Tree`
- `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Catalog`
- and More... !

I find it that any of these classes ***could*** facilitate my requirements - however I could be adding more technical debt without knowing it.

Magento 1 seems to have a good wealth of Developer Docs on Classes - But Magento 2 lacks this.

Is there a general convention that an experienced Magento developer goes by when knowing what requirements he requires to complete a task, or is this all down to a steep learning curve?

Apologies if this is a quite a broad question, not code specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding classes based on functionality in M2's codebase needs a little practice, but not much. They use some patterns or naming conventions that express their "reason of being" quite loudly.

I always start with the `Api` folder in a relevant M2 module (because I want to use *interfaces* as much as possible). There sit all the interfaces that I can use to pass into my ctor. It's those that usually have the naming convention I'm talking about. Take, for example, the [category repository interface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/a9bd85be4c1ab7176da9029ddf73ba14627cbef5/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/CategoryRepositoryInterface.php). By `Repository`, they mean "a thing that knows how to fetch or save an entity for me", loosely based on the [design pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

They also use `SomethingManagement` to mean something else; something that I invite you to figure out, as I had no luck.

Also, pay attention to the folders, too. Because they usually are in the class' namespace, you can easily find classes according to their folder, and vice-versa. `Model`, maps reality to business domain (Product, Cart etc.). `ResourceModel` contains classes that know how to speak with the DB. There are more, like `Observer`, `Setup`, `Block`. Some are convention, some are "convention, but you *must* use it".

Use interfaces *as much as possible*. Stay away from models, resource models and other lower-level classes *as much as possible*.

Some names are not obvious, other are plain wrong. There's no shortcuts there; only grief and <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Good luck.

---

PS: Use `Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface::get()` to check for a category. An entity-existence check in Magento usually means "Does it have an ID in DB?". So use `getId() !== null`.

---

PPS: You don't need to set up `di.xml` every time you need an object passed in your constructor. M2 checks your class' ctor arguments and will try to resolve them automatically. `di.xml` is for a better/manual control of said automatic injection (plus some other things, like injecting scalars and concrete instances, virtual types).

Comment: I am also learning and I found your answer very useful :) Thanks.

Comment: @nevvermind Morning! This is a great answer, sorry I haven't accepted just yet - I will after some time for other answers (it's a slower moving stacksite). Regardless, I made sense in your reasoning of the naming conventions - I think Investing in phpStorm for the better `cmd` + `f` might be wise :)